# TSQL Distinct Column in Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that is fetching communication data for a bulletin board. By default, its looking up all content located in the viewers department. However I allow them to select multiple departments to see the content around the company if they choose to..

The issue I am facing is that for each department they select, it is providing the same record multiple times.

In my query, in the `WHERE` clause, I have a statement that says `AND aud.Department IN (SELECT department FROM @departments)`.

This is where the error is occurring. For each department in that temp table, it returns the same record.

How can I go about selecting only distinct records from his table? `commID` is the identity

```
 -- Fetch our communicatons based on certain criteria
            SELECT   sub.commID,
                     sub.status,
                     sub.content,
                     CONVERT (VARCHAR (100), sub.distributionDate, 101) AS distributionDate,
                     sub.subject,
                     a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS approver,
                     b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName AS poc,
                     b.NTID AS NTID,
                     CONVERT (VARCHAR (100), sub.dateApproved, 101) AS dateApproved,
                     (SELECT department
                      FROM   comm_audience
                      WHERE  commID = sub.commID
                      FOR    XML PATH ('departments'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('audience'))
            FROM     comm_submissions AS sub
                     INNER JOIN
                     comm_medium AS med
                     ON sub.commID = med.commID
                     INNER JOIN
                     comm_mediumOptions AS mop
                     ON med.mediumID = mop.mediumID
                     INNER JOIN
                     comm_audience AS aud
                     ON sub.CommID = aud.commID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.EmployeeTable AS a
                     ON sub.approver = a.QID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.EmployeeTable AS b
                     ON sub.poc = b.QID
            WHERE    mop.mediumTitle IN ('Digital eBoard') -- Only eBoard Comms
                     AND aud.Department IN (SELECT department FROM @departments) -- Viewers Department must be in the audience
                     AND sub.commLocation = @locale -- The comm locale must be the viewers locale
                     AND sub.status IN ('Completed') -- Only show Approved or Completed Comms
            ORDER BY sub.distributionDate DESC
```

**-- Update**

```
-- Create a temp table of our department(s) we are viewing
DECLARE @departments as TABLE (department varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @departments(department)
SELECT  ParamValues.x1.value('department[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM    @xml.nodes('/root/data/departments/audience') AS ParamValues(x1);
```

Comment: where have you filled @departments, show it, (not the one who down voted)

Comment: Please show the smallest possible example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Updated to include MORE information than what I had :)

Comment: Have you tried running that last `SELECT  ParamValues.x1.value('department[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM    @xml.nodes('/root/data/departments/audience') AS ParamValues(x1);` separately? Are you certain that it gives back the distinct values you were intending to receive?

Comment: Its not that departments table thats the issue. It can contain 1 or more records and those will be unique. The problem is the WHERE clause. When you search `IN ()` It is providing you the data per record it finds in there

Comment: @SBB That is simply not true, or I am not understanding what you are saying correctly... Doing an `IN` in a `WHERE` clause will not duplicate records like a `LEFT JOIN` would, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Also, I'm not the one who down-voted (FYI).

Comment: For every department that gets added to the `@departments` table, the record is duplicated. However, when I query the `@departments` table, they are all unique departments.

Comment: The issue is here ` INNER JOIN comm_audience AS aud ON sub.CommID = aud.commID` as a submission can be linked to multiple allowed audiences. For each audience its finding on the inner join, its duplicating the record.

Comment: As SBB said, you shouldn't be joining on comm_audience. So remove that join and replace `AND aud.Department IN (SELECT department FROM @departments)` with something like `AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @departments AS D JOIN comm_audience AS aud ON aud.Department = D.Department WHERE sub.CommID = aud.commID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I understand is that your table **comm_audience** contains the departments you need to filter, but you can have multiple rows per commID. So in the where clause try filtering out the commID who are not in your list of departments like so:

```
     SELECT   sub.commID,
         sub.status,
         sub.content,
         CONVERT (VARCHAR (100), sub.distributionDate, 101) AS distributionDate,
         sub.subject,
         a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS approver,
         b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName AS poc,
         b.NTID AS NTID,
         CONVERT (VARCHAR (100), sub.dateApproved, 101) AS dateApproved,
         (SELECT department
          FROM   comm_audience
          WHERE  commID = sub.commID
          FOR    XML PATH ('departments'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('audience'))
FROM     comm_submissions AS sub
         INNER JOIN
         comm_medium AS med
         ON sub.commID = med.commID
         INNER JOIN
         comm_mediumOptions AS mop
         ON med.mediumID = mop.mediumID

         --Don't join here
         --INNER JOIN
         --(SELECT DISTINCT commID FROM comm_audience) AS aud
         --ON sub.CommID = aud.commID

         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.EmployeeTable AS a
         ON sub.approver = a.QID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.EmployeeTable AS b
         ON sub.poc = b.QID
WHERE    mop.mediumTitle IN ('Digital eBoard') -- Only eBoard Comms

         --Comment this out
         --AND aud.Department IN (SELECT department FROM @departments) -- Viewers Department must be in the audience

         --What you want is to filter out an commID that aren't in your list of departments so try this
         AND sub.CommID IN (SELECT DISTINCT commID FROM comm_audience WHERE Department IN (SELECT department FROM @departments))

         AND sub.commLocation = @locale -- The comm locale must be the viewers locale
         AND sub.status IN ('Completed') -- Only show Approved or Completed Comms
ORDER BY sub.distributionDate DESC
```

Comment: While this seems like it would work logically, I still get the duplicate results in the response. There are two tables that come into play with this issue. `comm_submissions` is what holds the submission data and its primary key is the `commID`. There is another tabled called `comm_audience` which contains a `commID` and any departments they selected to show this communication to. So there is one record in the submissions table to many in the audience table.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it this time. You only want commID who are in the departments so I edited my code so you want to do it in the where clause, not the join. Try it out.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed the issue, thanks so much!